# Ubuntu 18.04 can't find WiFi option in my dell laptop

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, wifi-hardware-switch

I used `rfkill list all` this command and i get only

```
1: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

How can i enable my WiFi option in my dell laptop

Comment: Maybe you could tell us what's your laptop model so it could help to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try `rfkill` without any options.

On my dell laptop, `rfkill` sees WiFi, Bluetooth, and 4G whereas `rfkill list all` reports only 4G.

Comment: ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked